# UPDATE table with FIRST matching row from another table without subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I am trying to adapt route management.

We have route codes that are tied to zipcode ranges. They are used to select correct route for transport to follow, when delivering orders.

A route will have zipcode range it is active for and may have a client -- if that route is specific for that client only.

So, routes table looks like this:

```
       route_no        | zipfrom | zipto |  client
-----------------------+---------+-------+----------
 ROUTE-CLIENTA-SPECIAL | 12330   | 12350 | CLIENT-A
 ROUTE-CLB1            | 33331   | 44445 | CLIENT-B
 ROUTE-SCENIC          | 11111   | 99999 |
(3 rows)
```

So, according to this table:

- every order must go ROUTE-SCENIC, including for clients CLIENT-A and CLIENT-B.
- UNLESS the order is for CLIENT-A AND the delivery is for address with zipcodes between 12330-12350 -- these go via ROUTE-CLIENTA-SPECIAL.
- OR it is order for CLIENT-B AND the order's zipcode is between 33331 and 44445 -- then it goes to route ROUTE-CLB1

So, for today's orders:

```
 order_id |  client  | route_no |  zip
----------+----------+----------+-------
 123      | CLIENT-A |          | 12345
 124      | CLIENT-A |          | 33333
 125      | CLIENT-A |          |
 N988     | CLIENT-B |          | 77777
 N987     | CLIENT-B |          | 33335
 N0981    | CLIENT-B |          | 44444
 N0983    | CLIENT-B |          | 12345
```

To get the possible routes for order N987 of CLIENT-B (zipcode 33333) I can do:

```
SELECT client,route_no FROM routes 
WHERE (client='CLIENT-B' OR client IS NULL )  
   AND '33333' BETWEEN zipfrom AND zipto ORDER BY client;

  client  |   route_no
----------+--------------
 CLIENT-B | ROUTE-CLB1
          | ROUTE-SCENIC
(2 rows)
```

Out of this ROUTE-CLB1 is the correct route (it is more specific to client than the default route).

I can select always the correct route by doing ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.

But I need to update the orders table with correct routes. I can do it with subquery:

```
UPDATE orders AS O 
   SET route_no=(SELECT R.route_no FROM routes R
              WHERE (O.client=R.client OR R.client IS NULL )
                    AND O.zip BETWEEN R.zipfrom AND R.zipto 
              ORDER BY R.client LIMIT 1);
```

This gives correct answers:

```
  id   |  client  |         route_no      |  zip
-------+----------+-----------------------+-------
 123   | CLIENT-A | ROUTE-CLIENTA-SPECIAL | 12345
 124   | CLIENT-A | ROUTE-SCENIC          | 33333
 125   | CLIENT-A |                       |
 N988  | CLIENT-B | ROUTE-SCENIC          | 77777
 N987  | CLIENT-B | ROUTE-CLB1            | 33335
 N0981 | CLIENT-B | ROUTE-CLB1            | 44444
 N0983 | CLIENT-B | ROUTE-SCENIC          | 12345
(7 rows)
```

But this tends to be very slow on larger order lists, as the subquery runs for every row.

How can I improve it? I tried to use DISTINCT ON as described in [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand it may sound complicated, but I am not sure where to go to make it easier. Perhaps you have some comment regarding what is not clear that could help me improve my question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

You might find that this is faster, with the right indexes:

```
UPDATE orders o
   SET route_no = COALESCE( (SELECT R.route_no
                             FROM routes R
                             WHERE O.client = R.client AND
                                   O.zip BETWEEN R.zipfrom AND R.zipto 
                             LIMIT 1
                            ), 
                            (SELECT R.route_no
                             FROM routes R
                             WHERE R.client IS NULL AND
                                   O.zip BETWEEN R.zipfrom AND R.zipto 
                             LIMIT 1
                            )
                           );
```

Then you want an index on `routes(client, zipfrom, zipto)`.  The index will at least quickly find the candidate rows in `routes` without scanning the table.  Postgres might figure that out with `or`, but this is worth a try.